# Cocos2d v3 - addChild method make performance problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i have currently a performance problem with the `addChild` method in cocos2d version 3.3. My scenario is currently that i have about ten `CCNode` which holds a bundle of other `CCNode` (about 500), i called those ten "Big Node".

The childs of the "Big Node" has their own childs (about 3). Those CCNodes are sprites.

None of the childs from "Big Node" runs any actions. Everthing happens in their update method (if this relevant).

In my main scene i figured out which "Big Node" are on screen. If their is a new "Big Node" or the old one is not anymore visible on the screen i run this code:

```
self = mainScene
_allBigNodes = holds all avaible big nodes

        NSMutableArray * childsToRemove = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: _children.count];

        for(CCNode * child in _children){
            if([child isKindOfClass:[BigNode class]]){
                [childsToRemove addObject:child];
            }
        }

        for(CCNode * child in childsToRemove){
            [child removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
        }

        [childsToRemove removeAllObjects];

        for(int BigNodeIndex = _fromBigNodePosition; BigNodeIndex<=_toBigNodePosition; ++BigNodeIndex){

            BigNode * BigNode = [_allBigNodes objectAtIndex: BigNodeIndex];

            [self addChild: BigNode];

        }
```

The main screen has normaly maximum two childs. The above method works fine.

In concerning to the question: sometimes in my game i have some jittery movement. So i figure out with the profiling tool that the addChild method above cost between 60-100ms.

```
Running Time    Self                        Symbol Name
90.0ms   79.6%  0.0                         -[CCNode addChild:]
90.0ms   79.6%  0.0                          -[CCNode addChild:z:name:]
89.0ms   78.7%  0.0                           -[CCNode onEnter]
88.0ms   77.8%  0.0                            -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]
88.0ms   77.8%  0.0                             -[CCNode onEnter]
72.0ms   63.7%  0.0                              -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]
71.0ms   62.8%  0.0                               -[CCNode onEnter]
42.0ms   37.1%  0.0                                -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]
42.0ms   37.1%  0.0                                 -[CCNode onEnter]
39.0ms   34.5%  0.0                                  -[CCScheduler scheduleTarget:]
38.0ms   33.6%  2.0                                   PrioritySearch
1.0ms    0.8%   1.0                                   DYLD-STUB$$objc::DenseMap<objc_object*, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_object*> >::grow(unsigned int)
1.0ms    0.8%   0.0                                  -[CCNode physicsNode]
1.0ms    0.8%   0.0                                   -[CCNode physicsNode]
1.0ms    0.8%   1.0                                  objc_msgSend
1.0ms    0.8%   1.0                                  objc_object::sidetable_release(bool)
28.0ms   24.7%  0.0                                -[CCScheduler scheduleTarget:]
26.0ms   23.0%  1.0                                 PrioritySearch
1.0ms    0.8%   0.0                                 -[CCScheduler scheduledTargetForTarget:insert:]
1.0ms    0.8%   1.0                                 DYLD-STUB$$objc_msgSend
1.0ms    0.8%   0.0                                -[CCNode physicsNode]
1.0ms    0.8%   1.0                               DYLD-STUB$$objc_msgSend
16.0ms   14.1%  0.0                              -[CCScheduler scheduleTarget:]
14.0ms   12.3%  0.0                               PrioritySearch
2.0ms    1.7%   0.0                               -[CCScheduler scheduledTargetForTarget:insert:]
1.0ms    0.8%   0.0                            -[CCScheduler scheduleTarget:]
1.0ms    0.8%   1.0                           -[CCNode wasRunning:]
```

So my question would be: Is there a way to deactivate a ccnode or what is the best solution to handle this scenario of having many ccnodes or these "Big Nodes" which are offscreen?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

500 nodes is *a lot of nodes*. You wouldn't want to add/remove them at runtime.

Instead, just change their parent's `visible` and `paused` properties when you don't need them to prevent them from rendering and running scheduled selectors and actions.

Comment: I have implement your solution. In addition to that I reduce the count of nodes to 50 for one Big Node. But I have still some times differences from 20-50 ms between the update,methods. Cause of that I still have some jittery movements. I profile the app and figure out that the update method takes know 15% CPU, but for example CCRender flush take 65 % CPU. I thought that the new version of cocos2d (version 3) can handle offscreen nodes. Is that correct?

Comment: It does not render offscreen nodes but the hundreds of nodes still add quite the overhead because the entire node graph still has to be traversed  every frame. Plus whatever code you run. ;)

Comment: Ok that make sense. So what's the best way to deal with so much nodes? It's a horizontal side scroll game. Do you have a good tutorial or a good idea? I stuck know in this problem for a few days and it's more or less one of the last steps in my game. Maybe we can chat if you want to help me.

Comment: Typically have only as many nodes as could be possibly on the screen at the same time, and then change their properties as needed (ie when scrolling). Keep the rest of the data in a custom data structure.

Comment: a question by the way: i currently track the time difference (which is was talking about) like this:

long long _lasMilli;

-(void) update: (CCTime) dt
{
    
    long long milliseconds = (long long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);
    
    if(milliseconds - _lasMilli >= 50){
        NSLog(@"%lld", (milliseconds - _lasMilli));
    }
    
    _lasMilli = milliseconds;

Is this a reliable method of tracking the time difference?